# Printing out translated Views' variables

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

I have a View, with its title translated to all enabled languages. When in tpl file I say: `print $views->human_name`, the title printed is stuck at the original language though. Any workaround for that, please?

Comment: Did you translate it with http://drupal.org/project/i18nviews?

Comment: Yes, from the Views' dropdown I chose "translate view" and provided the translations.

Comment: @kalabro Have you tried that? Does this work for you?

Comment: Yes, i18nviews works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$title = $view->get_title();
```

Views' human-readable name is just for developers and is not translated by i18nviews. You might want to get title.